# How to set a higher memory_limit, post_max_size, and for a specific script in Apache/PHP?

Tags: php, apache, memory

I have a web app that redirects all requests to the virtual host to a controller, which then decides which files to include and run based on the URL.  There is a web service that accepts large XML files through POST.  I need the memory_limit and post_max_ to be ~32M for the app, except for service that accepts the XML, which will need their limits to be closer to 1024M.  `ini_set('memory_limit','1024M')` works within the script, but won't work for the post_max_size.

I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I was trying something similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/html


php_admin_value include_path .:/var/www/test.com/includes:/var/www/test.com/includes/libs

php_value session.use_only_cookie 1
<Location />
    php_value memory_limit 32M
    php_value post_max_size 30M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 29M
</Location>
<Location /services/big-service>
    php_value memory_limit 1024M
    php_value post_max_size 128M
</Location>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)(html|gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js|dtd|swf|flv|xml)$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /Controller.php/$1 [PT]

</VirtualHost>
```

So, with the above config, if Controller.php looks like

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'));
var_dump(ini_get('post_max_size'));
var_dump(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
```

I'll receive
    string(3) "32M"
    string(3) "30M"
    string(3) "29M"

if I visit http://test.com, and http://test.com/services/big-service, but I'd like to see the higher limits for the later URLs.

Does anybody have any solutions to this that don't resort to using  and accessing the service script directly through the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is mod_rewrite is causing it to always go to /Controller.php, so the Location block with the services is never used.  Using additional mod_rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/services/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)(html|gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js|dtd|swf|flv|xml)$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /ControllerBig.php/services/$1 [PT]
```

And then having ControllerBig be a clone of Controller

```
<?php
require_once('Controller.php');
```

will work.

**Edit: Full VirtualHost block:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/html

php_admin_value include_path .:/var/www/test.com/includes:/var/www/test.com/includes/libs

php_value session.use_only_cookie 1
<Location />
    php_value memory_limit 32M
    php_value post_max_size 30M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 29M
</Location>
<Location /services/big-service>
    php_value memory_limit 1024M
    php_value post_max_size 128M
</Location>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/services/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)(html|gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js|dtd|swf|flv|xml)$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /ControllerBig.php/services/$1 [PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)(html|gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js|dtd|swf|flv|xml)$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /Controller.php/$1 [PT]

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deciding at runtime which web service the client is looking for, you are limited to what you can do.  You cannot use multiple php.ini files, because once PHP is executing your script, you are stuck with the .ini file that instance used.

The best bet in this case is to set the larger limits in php.ini, and then use ini_set() directives in your scripts to bring that limit down.  If that's unacceptable, then the best you could do is set only post_max_size to the larger limit, and then set each of your other limits individually within your script.

The problem is that by the time PHP starts executing your script, it has already read its post_max_size from php.ini, and the data has already been POSTed to your server, so if this limit has been exceeded, your script won't even be executed.

Comment: Yes, having a post_max_size larger than memory_limit is an issue, as it will Fatal out (memory exhausted) when a large post comes by.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK php.ini is one per php instance (php5_module), you may work around your problem
by running several of them.

1. as php5_module is one per apache, one solutions would be to run
   another Apache instance. Problem is that it can not run in same port 80
2. setup FCGI to parse php along with php5_module.
   this way you can give different startup params for each. you would need
   to rename your scripts to something other than .php for fcgi to parse(.fcgi maybe)

sample

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so  

LoadModule php5_module c:/apps/php/php5apache2_2.dll
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/apps/php/ini1"

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi 
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "c:/apps/php/ini2"
FcgidWrapper "c:/apps/php/php-cgi.exe" .fcgi
AddType    application/x-httpd-fcgi .fcgi
</IfModule>
```

Not sure how crash-proof this setup is however, heh

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a new Name based virtualhost (so with another **DNS**) handling the same configuration, with some changes on the memory limit.

This means your application urls for /services/big-service should always use this different DNS (and your application should check theses services are always taken from the right url.

The php_value settings can be set by VirtualHost, so it should work. If you check [this table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) you'll see that memory_limit is not in PERDIR scope, so you cannot set it only for a Directory, only the complete VirtualHost. With a PERDIR scope a `<Directory>` may have been able to catch the thing instead of `<Location>` (but anyway you may have a mod_rewrite to the main index.php file, so it's always the same Directory).

With the 2 DNS solution you still have one big problem, you may get some of your apache process consuming 1024M of RAM, and they will later be used for more simple requests, but still take this RAM. So you would have to clean-up often your apache children (MaxRequestPerChild to 100 for example).

Even with the Fcgid of php-fpm solution, so without mod_php, you will make your PHP script consume a lot of RAM and this is not the nicest things to do (you should test what happen to your RAM when 10%/30%/50% of client requests are using these services, and how your php RAM usage is cleanup up - or not). You should check the [Zend_Memory](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.memory.html) component, it should be usable as a library component with Zend_Cache elements as well, it will manage a *'swapp memory to cache'* for you, avoiding too much RAM usage in your big-service.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will work. Since, the redirection always goes to Controller.php and I don't think Apache will support to have various php.ini value based on the Location.

If /services/big-service is a directory then it make sense to accept the values for the PHP, I would suggest you have a common php.ini value or create a directory and write a .htaccess to have it's own php settings.